# find docker name in a node.js application running inside docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-container

I have a node.js application running inside a docker container with base image node:16-alpine3.11.
I want to get the name of the container on which it is running on.

```
ex:
docker ps:

CONTAINER ID     NAMES
xyz               node

test.js:
const c_name= //get container name
```

Comment: What will you do with it once you have it?  If you don't otherwise override it, if the process tries to determine its own hostname, it will get back the container ID, which could be useful just to tell different log streams apart.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could pass the name as environment variable. You could mount `/var/run/docker.sock` as read-only bind mount and try to find what you need using the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From outside the container**

You can use the docker cli to do this. In the example we filter for ancestor `bitnami/redis` (in your case this would be `node:16-alpine3.11`)

```
$ docker container ls --filter "ancestor=bitnami/redis" --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}"
```

This returns the id, name and image of the container as a table. To retrieve the results as a json object, update the format flag like below:

```
docker container ls --filter "ancestor=bitnami/redis" --format 'json { "Id":"{{.ID}}", "Image": "{{.Image}}", "Names": "{{.Names}}" }'
```

See the handy [cli reference docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) provided by docker.

**From Inside the Container**

Pass the unix socket to the container and invoke a script to get the container name:

```
$ docker run -it -v "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock" origami-duckling:latest
```

The Dockerfile for `origami-duckling looks like this:

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11

WORKDIR /usr/app

RUN apk add curl jq
ENV DOCKER_HOST="unix:///run/docker.sock"

COPY get-container-name.sh /usr/app/get-container-name.sh
CMD /usr/app/get-name.sh
```

> You would probably run the get-container-name before you use `cmd` to run the node app in your container.

The `get-container-name.sh` would look like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
export CONTAINER_NAME="$(curl -s --unix-socket /run/docker.sock http://docker/containers/$HOSTNAME/json | jq '.Name')"

echo $CONTAINER_NAME
```

Update: You can do this from within your node.js app if you need to:

> I'm using got@11.8.3, got 12.x is pure ESM.

```js
const got = require('got');
async function getHostName() {
  const metadata = await got(`http://unix:/var/run/docker.sock:/containers/${process.env.HOSTNAME}/json`).json();

  console.log('Container name', metadata.Name);
  return metadata.Name
}
```

Comment: @jabaa I have updated the answer to include how we can get it from inside the container.